# Get gitlab/gitlab-ce working with macvlan on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ce, macvlan

The following docker-compose.yml file below was supposed to bring up gitlab's gitlab-ce on my local network using docker's macvlan. However, I am unable to view gitlab-ce in a browser or ping the assigned Ip. After inspecting the resulting container I see that while the container is indeed assigned an IP address on my network,

```
"Gateway": "10.0.1.1",
"IPAddress": "10.0.1.2"
```

, it does not assign the HostIp.

```
"NetworkMode": "config_frontend",
"PortBindings": {
    "22/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "",
            "HostPort": "22"
        }
    ],
    "443/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "",
            "HostPort": "443"
        }
    ],
    "80/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "",
            "HostPort": "80"
        }
    ]
},
```

How do I update my docker-compose.yml file ?

```
version: '3'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 services:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  gitlab-server:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    networks:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - './data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    restart: always
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eno1.10
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.1.0/24
```